# Generating functions, problem solving. Distribute distinguishable balls to people

Tags: combinatorics, problem-solving

The problem reads:

*How many ways are there to distribute $26$ of $34$ distinguishable balls to $5$ people if Lucy gets at most $4$ balls?*

The generating function to distribute distinguishable balls to $5$ people is:

$$
e^{4z}(1+z+z^2/2!+z^3/3!+z⁴/4!)
$$

So the answer is the $26th$ coefficient of this expression, multiplied by the ways in which one can choose 26 balls among 34, which give me the answer:

$$
\binom{34}{26}e^{4z}(1+z+z^2/2!+z^3/3!+z⁴/4!)
$$

The answer of the book is $\binom{34}{12}e^{4z}(1+z+z^2/2!+z^3/3!+z⁴/4!)$, I want to understand what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Just a guess, but maybe whoever wrote the solutions accidentally subtracted $26$ from $34$ and got $12$?

Comment: That's what I would like to know, and that if I have something wrong with my reasoning. Since I am learning enumerative combinatorics on my own, I'm not so overconfident to ignore the typos.

Answer (score 1):

I can tell you that much, your reasoning seams quite correct. However I am a little bit shocked from such a typo in a book, which one?

Because $e^{4 z}(1 + z + z^2/2! + z^3/3! + z^4/4! )$ is the egf of the number of ways to distribute $n$ distinguishable balls for 5 people where one of them gets at most 4.

I can only imagine that it was an unfortunate attempt to simplify ${34 \choose 26}$

Comment: It is the book _Counting: the art of enumerative combinatorics_ by George Martin. I have to say that if it is a typo this would be just the second (for me it is a very well written book!). Section 29, __Five review exercises__, number 2.

Comment: Looks like it’s this book: http://www.amazon.com/dp/038795225X/ref=rdr_ext_tmb. The posted solution is visible via the “Look Inside!” link, and the question (a review question in Chapter 3) is visible here: https://books.google.com/books?id=TiXaBwAAQBAJ&lpg=PA64&dq=%22How%20many%20ways%20are%20there%20to%20distribute%2026%22%20lucy&pg=PA64#v=onepage&q=%22How%20many%20ways%20are%20there%20to%20distribute%2026%22%20lucy&f=false